# Strange graphical error with KDE

Tags: kubuntu, intel-graphics, visual-artifacts

Link to current progress which has been little unfortunately.
http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?60891-Weird-Composition-error&p=314029
I am having a  weird artifact and screen tearing issue.  It is a very eratic issues as sometimes it is not there and other times is it every where.  It happens a lot on right click menus.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0551]
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:11a0] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:057b]
```

[image: The white boxes]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ever since i installed Kubuntu. I fixed it by simply updating all of my packages. If that doesn't work, I'd suggest disabling all of your desktop effects in settings and re-enabling them until the boxes reappear.

Comment: And I also have an Intel 3rd generation graphics processor.